# Pushing new UIViewController from custom UIPopOver issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Hello I'm using this [library](https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController) to show my PopOver which contain tableView with searchBar. 
The problem is that one user try to select row from the tableView instead dismissing the popOver and displaying the slected row in hole screen I got this :
[image].
I've tried to use `[self.parentViewController.navigationController ...]` to push my view but didn't worked.

This is my popOver code (in MainVC.h):

```
-(IBAction)showPopoverSearch:(id)sender{


UIBarButtonItem *btn = (UIBarButtonItem *) sender;
NSInteger width = 600;
NSInteger height = 400;

SearchViewController *searchVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchView"];


searchVC.modalInPopover = NO;
UINavigationController* contentViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchVC];

popoverController = [[WYPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController];
popoverController.delegate = self;
//popoverController.passthroughViews = @[btn];
popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
popoverController.popoverLayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
popoverController.wantsDefaultContentAppearance = YES;

[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:btn permittedArrowDirections:WYPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

}

And this is the `didSelctRow` method (SearchViewController.m) :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"bundle:nil];
    PostReaderViewController *postReaderView =
    (PostReaderViewController *)
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"postReader"];
    postReaderView.thePost = [_postsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//    if ([self.parentViewController.po .popoverController isPopoverVisible])
//        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:postReaderView animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: you have to call dismissPopoverAnimated method

Comment: @UttamSinha have you headed my post carrefully ?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I've passed the Navigation controller and popoverController from The parent View `MainVC.h` to child controller `SearchViewController.h` and then use those vars to dismiss my PopOvercontroller and push the new VC. Code snippet :
**SearchView**

```
@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) WYPopoverController *parentPopoverVC;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *parentNavigationController;
@end

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     ...
    [self.parentPopoverVC dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    [self.parentNavigationController pushViewController:postReaderView animated:YES];

}
```

**MainVC.h**

```
-(IBAction)showPopoverSearch:(id)sender{

    SearchViewController *searchVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchView"];
    [searchVC setParentPopoverVC:popoverController];
    [searchVC setParentNavigationController:self.navigationController];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:btn permittedArrowDirections:WYPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}
```